# Graph not redrawing properly

Tags: d3.js

I'm currently trying to combine two of my graphs into one view. My second graph, the bar chart will update the data if you use the slider. When you slide it forward, it works fine and dandy but when you slide it backwards it doesn't redraw the chart. When I was working on the bar chart separately it was fully working, it just seems that when I combine it with the line graph that it's only partially working.

I'm trying to find the cause of the problem and I think it's something wrong with this block of code. If I comment it out the bar graph redraws properly.

```
var chart1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", chart1_width + chart1_margin.left + chart1_margin.right)
.attr("height", chart1_height + chart1_margin.top + chart1_margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + chart1_margin.left + "," + chart1_margin.top + ")");
```

Link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/flyingburrito/a8fym1ma/3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the bar chart on top and that made it work fine. An easy solution would be to keep it like that.

A better solution would be to analyse why that happens. With D3 when things happen like this it will often be in your selects. That is your problem here

```
    d3.select("#sexYear").on("input", function () {
    debugger;
    d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect").remove();
    update(this.value);        
});
```

You are selecting 'svg' which selects the first svg which is the line chart, not the bar chart. This is because 'd3.select' selects the first of whatever is being called. What I did was add a class called 'barchart' to the barchart and then I select the barchart as such

```
var chart2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr('class','barchart')
```

and

```
d3.select("#sexYear").on("input", function () {
    debugger;
    d3.select(".barchart").selectAll("rect").remove();
    update(this.value);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8fym1ma/6/)

Comment: Note that you can do this without adding a class and use the pseudo selector [n-th child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). I suppose it's up to preference but I personally don't find it as clean.